# Constructing a Bash command with arguments containing spaces, pipes and process substitution

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a small utility script that can be parametrized to additionally `time` its execution and also write its stdout to another file.

Let's assume the basic script is simply:

```
ls "$@"
```

Then the following would be a naïve implementation, here using `cat` as a dummy for more complex handling of the output:

```
if [[ "$TIMEIT" -eq 1 ]]; then
  if [[ "$LOGIT" -eq 1 ]]; then
    time ls "$@" | tee >(cat)
  else
    time ls "$@"
  fi
else
  if [[ "$LOGIT" -eq 1 ]]; then
    ls "$@" | tee >(cat)
  else
    ls "$@"
  fi
fi
```

You can see what the probiem is with that, particularly if new parameters should be added.

A rewrite that would be more flexible is:

```
cmd="ls $@"

if [[ "$TIMEIT" -eq 1 ]]; then
  cmd="time $cmd"
fi

if [[ "$LOGIT" -eq 1 ]]; then
  cmd="$cmd | tee >(cat)"
fi

eval $cmd
```

This works, but it breaks once you call it as:

```
./script.sh "file 1" file2
```

Because the file names will not be handled properly.

When I apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52565509/435093), I can properly tokenize the arguments when prepending the command with `time`:

```
function token_quote {
  local quoted=()
  for token; do
    quoted+=( "$(printf '%q' "$token")" )
  done
  printf '%s\n' "${quoted[*]}"
}

cmd=(ls "$@")

if [[ "$TIMEIT" -eq 1 ]]; then
  cmd=(time "${cmd[@]}")
fi

eval "$(token_quote "${cmd[@]}")"
```

But the same method for handling the pipe does not work. When I adapt it using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16992934/435093):

```
function eval_args {
  local quoted=''
  while (( $# )); do
    if [[ $1 = '|' ]]; then
      quoted+="| "
    else
      printf -v quoted '%s%q ' "$quoted" "$1"
    fi
    shift
  done
  eval "$quoted"
}

cmd=(ls "$@")

# prepend to array
if [[ "$TIMEIT" -eq 1 ]]; then
  cmd=(time "${cmd[@]}")
fi

# append to array?
if [[ "$LOGIT" -eq 1 ]]; then
  cmd=("${cmd[@]}" "|" "tee" ">(cat)")
fi

eval_args "${cmd[@]}"
```

It creates a file `>(cat)` … so I'm going down the rabbit hole here, and it seems like this is not the way to go.

What can I do to construct the command and handle spaces/special chararacters in filenames, including pipes/process substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Eval

Your last method might work, as long as you skip it for your custom additions and only use it for generating the original command. That is, change eval_args to only *build* the command string:

```
build_args() {
    local arg quoted=""
    for arg; do
        printf -v quoted '%s%q ' "$quoted" "$1"
    done
    echo "$quoted"
}

cmd=$(build_args ls "$@")
if (( TIMEIT )); then
    cmd="time $cmd"
fi
if (( LOGIT )); then
    cmd="$cmd | tee >(foo)"
fi

eval "$cmd"
```

Actually the loop is unnecessary, as bash's printf will automatically repeat the same format string with extra arguments:

```
argv=(ls -la "$@")
cmd=$(printf '%q ' "${argv[@]}")
eval "time $cmd | tee >(foo)"
```

Bash 5.1 has a `${foo@Q}` modifier which is a more convenient alternative:

```
argv=(ls -la "$@")
cmd=${argv[*]@Q}
eval "time $cmd | tee >(foo)"
```

#### Alternative to eval

Let's say your script has its main code in a function:

```
run() { ls "$@"; }
```

You can conditionally define a wrapper function for it:

```
if (( LOGIT )); then
    run_logged() { run "$@" | tee >(cat); }
else
    run_logged() { run "$@"; }
fi

if (( TIMEIT )); then
    run_timed() { time run_logged "$@"; }
else
    run_timed() { run_logged "$@"; }
fi

run_timed "$@"
```

(The function definition itself could be generated into a string and eval'd.)

#### Reexec

In some cases, it might make sense to re-execute the entire script under the new environment:

```
if (( UID > 0 )); then
    exec sudo "$0" "$@" || exit
fi

if (( ! _LOGIT_ACTIVE )); then
    exec _LOGIT_ACTIVE=1 "$0" "$@" | tee >(foo) || exit
fi

ls "$@"
```

#### Misc

As for redirects specifically, you could hardcode the use of `tee` and only swap the filename (not very efficient as it still causes tee to run and duplicate writes, but... it does the job):

```
if (( LOGIT )); then
    out=/var/log/foo
else
    out=/dev/null
fi

ls "$@" | tee $out
```

Same for straightforward redirections to a file:

```
if (( LOGIT )); then
    exec {fd}>/var/log/foo
else
    fd=1     # stdout
fi

ls "$@" >&$fd

if (( fd != 1 )); then
    exec {fd}>&-    # close
fi
```

Alternatively you could pipe into a condition, or a function that wraps the condition (also not 100% efficient due to mandatory `cat`):

```
ls "$@" | if (( LOGIT )); then tee >(whatever); else cat; fi
```

Comment: Very comprehensive, thank you.

Comment: Using the solution with on-demand function definition, assuming I am not using the builtin `time` but an external command, it will complain that `run_logged` is not found. Any workaround for that?

Comment: Somewhat ugly one: `export -f run run_logged; /bin/time bash -c 'run_logged "$@"' -- "$@"` (untested)